# Compiling program within another program using gcc

Tags: c

From command line I am getting file name which I have to compile using gcc. lets say its like this.

```
./a.out fileToBeCompiled.c
```

Then how I can compile this file using gcc within my program? lets say main.c for which a.out is being made.

Comment: Without shelling out: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189949/is-there-a-way-to-use-gcc-as-a-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always call gcc to compile from an shell execution command within your program.

[Reference to the system function.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/)

Comment: Using system is a bad idea, but if it works for itsaboutcode, it shall be fine with me

Answer (score 7):

Just exec gcc from within you program.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   execv("/usr/bin/gcc", argv);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to call [`fork()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html), [`exec()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exec.html), and [`wait()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/wait.html).  You probably want to use `execv()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you can use the function "system"(defined inside stdio.h) to execute the unix command inside the c, c++ programs.

For Example: I am going to compile sub.c inside main.c

```
void main(void)
{
  system("cc sub.c -o sub");
}
```

You can specify the dynamic input and output files.

Answer (score 0):

```
./a.out fileToBeCompiled.c && gcc fileToBeCompiled.c
```

If `./a.out` fails (it it returns something other than 0) gcc will not be called